# BIGQUERY: How to query for a rolling monthly user active/churn

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

So I have a website with news articles and I'm trying to calculate 4 user types for each month. The user types are:

**1. New User:** A user who registers (their first article view) in the current month and viewed an article in the current month.

**2. Retained User:** A New User from the previous month OR a user who viewed an article in the previous month and in the current month.

**3. Churned User:** A New User or Retained User from the previous month who has not viewed an article in the current month OR a Churned User from the previous month.

**4. Resurrected User:** A Churned User from the previous month who has viewed an article in the current month.

```
**User Table A - Unique User Article Views**
- Current month = 2019-04-01 00:00:00 UTC

| user_id    | viewed_at                 |
------------------------------------------
| 4          | 2019-04-01 00:00:00 UTC   |
| 3          | 2019-04-01 00:00:00 UTC   |
| 2          | 2019-04-01 00:00:00 UTC   |
| 1          | 2019-03-01 00:00:00 UTC   |
| 3          | 2019-03-01 00:00:00 UTC   |
| 2          | 2019-02-01 00:00:00 UTC   |
| 1          | 2019-02-01 00:00:00 UTC   |
| 1          | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 UTC   |


The table above outlines the following user types:

2019-01-01
* User 1: New

2019-02-01
* User 1: Retained
* User 2: New

2019-03-01
* User 1: Retained
* User 2: Churned
* User 3: New

2019-04-01
* User 1: Churned
* User 2: Resurrected
* User 3: Retained
* User 4: New
```

My desired table COUNTS the distinct user_id for each user type in each month.

```
| month_viewed_at           | ut_new | ut_retained | ut_churned | ut_resurrected
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2019-04-01 00:00:00 UTC   | 1      | 1           | 1          | 1
| 2019-03-01 00:00:00 UTC   | 1      | 1           | 1          | 0
| 2019-02-01 00:00:00 UTC   | 1      | 1           | 0          | 0
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 UTC   | 1      | 0           | 0          | 0
```

Comment: @mikhail would you have any solutions for this question?

Comment: I know how to do this.  Have fun.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff would appreciate any help you could provide.

Comment: You should show what you tried so far, otherwise it looks like you are outsourcing your work! We all here love to help users like you, but you should respect our willingness to help by first actually trying something and show it so we can HELP

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant that's absolutely fair and I would, I simply am not sure where to start. Certainly not looking to outsource, just need some help.

Comment: I would start searching here on SO, there should be number of similar posts to help you start. Note: answering such cold questions is considered here on SO as a bad manner! It might be ok for first or second time, but ...

Comment: Ok, thanks @MikhailBerlyant. You can probably tell I'm a bit if a newbie here. Sorry for any offense, not my intention.

Comment: No problem, anyway someone will answer. But if you try by yourself - will be great for you

Comment: also, have in mind "You can only @reply to users who have already left a comment, or edited the post". You can see more [about comments on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) so user reference in your first comment has no effect at all :o) and yet again about asking question - you can check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I simply am not sure where to start

Hope you read all my comments and actually tried something by yourself, but as I don't see any update I suppose you still stuck here - so here we go ...

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and should give you direction

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp1 AS (
  SELECT user_id,
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', DATE(viewed_at)) month_viewed_at, 
    DATE_DIFF(DATE(viewed_at), '2000-01-01', MONTH) pos,
    DATE_DIFF(DATE(MIN(viewed_at) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id)), '2000-01-01', MONTH) first_pos
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), temp2 AS (
  SELECT *, pos = first_pos AS new_user
  FROM temp1
), temp3 AS (
  SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(new_user) OVER(win) OR pos - 1 = LAST_VALUE(pos) OVER(win) AS retained_user
  FROM temp2
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY pos RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
)
SELECT month_viewed_at,
  COUNTIF(new_user) AS new_users,
  COUNTIF(retained_user) AS retained_users
FROM temp3
GROUP BY month_viewed_at
-- ORDER BY month_viewed_at DESC
```

If to apply to your sample data - result is

```
Row month_viewed_at new_users   retained_users   
1   2019-04         1           1    
2   2019-03         1           1    
3   2019-02         1           1    
4   2019-01         1           0
```

In `temp1` we preparing data by formatting viewed_at to needed format to present in output ad also we are transforming it to present consecutive number of month since some abstract data (2000-02-02) so we can use analytics function with RANGE as opposed to ROWS
In `temp2` we just simply identifying new users and in `temp3` - retained users

I think, this can be good start, so I am leaving the rest for you

Comment: Hi @mikhail, thank you very much. This is incredibly helpful!!!! I wasn't able to get much together before this help and built it manually in Google Sheets, so thank you.

Comment: @Livewire - glad it helped and you made it!!! I was worry that you might be offended by the way I commented - but my intention was only to push you right direction.

Comment: definitely wasn't offended. I appreciate the tips of SO question. Thank you again!!!!